# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In this line of code

```
  <% var tmp = int.Parse(ViewData["numOfGroups"].ToString()); %>
```

I have error:`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.   How correctly convert

`ViewData["numOfGroups"]` to `int`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first make sure that your controller action is setting this variable:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["numOfGroups"] = "15";
    return View();
}
```

Once you've done this you should no longer get a `NullReferenceException` and your code should work.

Of course as I've already written it multiple times here you should prefer strongly typed view instead of `ViewData`. Also you should type your model properties accordingly. It is not the responsibility of the view to parse strings. So:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel
    {
        NumOfGroups = 15
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

And in your view:

```
<% var tmp = Model.NumOfGroups; %>
```

By the way this should also be avoided as I have the feeling that you are declaring variables in your view which means that you have the intent of using them. Views are not for declaring variables and writing C# code. They are markup.

Answer (score 1):

If the error was related to converting `ViewData["numOfGroups"]` to int then you would get [FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx). Check that you are really passing data to the view and that it contains `numOfGroups` key.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `ViewData["numOfGroups"]` is null. It is quite possible that problem is not in conversion itself but in  `ViewData["numOfGroups"].ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since ViewData dictionary contains `<string, object>` you have to do unboxing on the value:

```
int tmp = (int)ViewData["numOfGroups"];
```

but check if the object is null first or surround by try/catch if there's any chance the conversion will not work...
...or use `TryParse()` that returns bool if the conversion succeeded or not.

Comment: your code will not compile I guess you meant (int)ViewData["numOfGroups"] which however will still be a null ref exception. The most plausible null ref exception in the code OP posted is that ViewData["NoOfGRoups"] is null.